# Setting component scope variable in a nested function

Tags: angular

I am trying set 'records' variable in component and then view it on 'list.html' ..How can i achieve it?

```
angular.module('myApp').component('listTransactions',{
    templateUrl:'list.html',
    controllerAs:'listTransCtrl',
    controller:function (){
    this.records=''; // I am trying to assign a value to this variable    
        var db = openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_NAME_VISIBLE, DATABASE_SIZE);
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+TABLE_NAME, [], function (tx, result) {
                    var len = result.rows.length;
                    var transactions = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        var transaction = result.rows.item(i);
                        transactions.push(transaction);
                    }

                   records=transactions;//How can I assign 'transactions' to variable 'records' in here ? 

                }, function (tx, error) {

                });

            });
    }
});
```

My view : list.html

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <span>{{listTransCtrl.records}}</span> <!-- Where I am expecting to see contents of 'records'-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer code is attached below**

```
angular.module('myApp').component('listTransactions',{
    templateUrl:'list.html',
    controllerAs:'listTransCtrl',
    controller:function ($timeout){
        var vm = this;
        vm.records = '';

            var db = openDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_NAME_VISIBLE, DATABASE_SIZE);
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM '+TABLE_NAME, [], function (tx, result) {
                        var len = result.rows.length;
                        var transactions = [];
                        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            var transaction = result.rows.item(i);
                            transactions.push(transaction);
                        }

                       $timeout(function() {
                           vm.records = transactions;
                           console.log(vm.records);
                        });


                    }, function (tx, error) {

                    });

                });
    }
});
```

Comment: Issue? Can you check the console and post the log?

Comment: {{listTransCtrl.records}} is still empty when i print it on console

Comment: $timeout fixed the problem, thank you. Can you tell me why we need to use $timeout ?

Comment: Angular used $scope to achieve two way binding where changes are reflected at both of the sides (html & model) but this happens only when we update scope in angular context. But if we change scope value in any non angular context (e.g. method or callback) then we use $timeout to refresh scope manually.